# CSS Animation Spin - Not Spinning in Place Anymore

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an image then I have applied the following style rules to:

```
.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation:spin 14s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 14s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);} }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform: rotate(-360deg);}}
```

In my IDE, this works perfectly fine. I then published a page to the web about 6 months ago. I loaded the page, and it worked as expected. Actually things were good, no problems or anything for all those 6 months. Then a few weeks ago I noticed a strange development -- the rotation behavior changed. I was bewildered because this page, and indeed, the entire site is static. There have been no updates to the master css file or anything for that matter that could possibly interfere with the style rules that I posted above.

Specifically what changed was instead of the image rotating in place **at** its center, the image now rotates **about** its original center position. The easiest way to imagine the change in behavior is comparing it to a clock. The center of the clock doesn't move as the hands rotate. However the minute hand and hour hands do (namely the ends of the hands that point to the time). That is what my image is doing now. It's now moving across the x and y dimensions in pixel space when it is not supposed to. It's supposed to rotate in place, staying still. There should be no movement in x or y.

I said to myself, "well this is just impossible," and thought the problem would go away by itself just as mysteriously as it came. Unfortunately it persisted for a few weeks, so I feel compelled to deal with it. Despite the absence of style rule clashes, I added `!important` to all the style rules that I posted above for the `.spinner` class as well as the `@keyframes` out of scope as well. This didn't help.

Now I'm starting to think it could be a browser issue? I'm using google chrome; only google chrome, I didn't include any `-moz`, I won't need to. My only guess is that the browser updated itself and started handling these animations differently?

**Question:** Why would `animation:spin` change spinning behavior? Is this symptomatic of some other looming issue? Is there anything I can do to make my rules more robust, other than add `!important`?

- Chrome version: 64.0.3282.186

**Update** After what seemed like a billion trial and errors, I found that by setting:

```
.spinner {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 15% 0%;
}
```

The image started to spin in place like it used to. Still begs the question what happened...

I examined the image to see if it's dimensions had changed somehow, but things look normal.

Comment: Why aren't you using the unprefixed transform-origin?

Comment: @jhpratt Good call, I tried that too just now. It's odd, still not working.  Thanks for looking into it though

Comment: "length: 600px" ?

Comment: haha, that was a typo, changed to height

Comment: Can you force your rotation to be in the desired axis by saying, e.g.. rotateX or rotateY? That should work in all browsers.

Comment: @ecg8 another good idea, but I was only able to achieve 3D effects with those. I just need 2d spinning for now. For some reason the origin is not at the right place. I tried reverse engineering by changing `transform-origin` to other percentages to "humor" it. Made some progress, but not consistent.

Comment: I guess my problem is conceptualizing what you are trying to have happen. When you say "There should be no movement in x or y", then mustn't there have to be movement in Z? If not, what is supposed to move.

Answer (score 0):

**A bit late at 2021.5**  But may be helpful for somebody. In my case it was because I removed :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and then caught that. All the followings were untouched ,the css were:

```
#overlay {
 display: none;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99999;
}

.myblock {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: center;
 horiz-align: center;
 -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
 transform-origin: center center;
 -moz-transform-origin: center;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="myblock" style="background-color: transparent; background-blend-mode: unset">
    <img src="/images/corona.png" width="150px" height="150px" style="background-blend-mode: unset"
         alt="this slowpoke moves"/>
 </div>
</div>

....//other divs
 </div>
</body>
```

the js part:

```
function spinIt(gironPrm) {
    if (gironPrm === true)
        $("#overlay").css('display', 'flex')
    else
        $("#overlay").css('display', 'none')
}
```

I have no idea no care of its science  and no time to figure out  why it happened to me,
but its so  as it is